# Setting video gravity to resizeAspectFill leads to some videos with improper aspect ratios result in bottom and top black bars (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have looked into similar questions but I have a different issue.

So, there are certain videos (which we don't have control over) where in the aspect ratio is not 16:9 but they are made 16:9 by inserting black bars in the video content on the top and bottom. In such videos setting the videoGravity to resizeAspectFill still leaves bottom and top bars. Here's the code:

```
if self.playerLayer?.videoGravity == .resizeAspect {
    self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
} else {
    self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
}
```

I have looked into scaling of the layer by applying a transform but that leads to the subtitles looking out of place. Is there any other way so that we can somehow zoom in more so that these black bars are completely invisible?